# Derived class calling a base class method with specific arguments

Tags: c++, overloading, virtual

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Thing {
    void foo(bool b = true) {
        std::cout << "Thing::foo() called with b = " << std::boolalpha << b << ".\n";
    }
};

struct Blob : Thing { };

struct Event {
    void execute(Thing& thing) { thing.foo(); }
};

int main() {
    Blob blob;
    Event event;
    event.execute(blob);
}
```

Output:

```
Thing::foo() called with b = true.
```

Suppose we want the output:

```
Thing::foo() called with b = false.
```

when `Thing` is of type `Blob` (and many other derived classes of `Thing` not mentioned here), but ONLY when called from `Event`, and any classes derived from `Event`.

The overload solution:

```
struct Event {
    void execute(Thing& thing) { thing.foo(); }
    void execute(Blob& blob) { blob.foo(false); }
};
```

is not the ideal solution because there are many other derived classes of `Thing` that would need such overloads (and this list of such derived classes will constantly increase as the program evolves
so a template metaprogramming solution won't be ideal either).

One solution I thought of is to introduce a virtual method:

```
struct Thing {
    void foo(bool b = true) {
        std::cout << "Thing::foo() called with b = " << std::boolalpha << b << ".\n";
    }
    virtual void fooDuringEvent(bool b = true) { foo(b); }
};

struct Blob : Thing {
    void fooDuringEvent(bool = true) override { foo(false); }
};

struct Event {
    void execute(Thing& thing) { thing.fooDuringEvent(); }
};
```

This works, but it is easy to mistakenly call `foo()` instead of `fooDuringEvent()` when it is needed, for example

```
struct Task : Event {
    void execute(Thing& thing) {
        // Stuff
        thing.foo();  // Oops!
        // Other stuff
    }
};
```

So what is the best solution to handle this problem?

Comment: @  Mooing Duck  Only when called from `Event` or any derived type of it, and only for `Blob` and many other derived types of `Thing` that will be discovered as the program evolves.  Something is special about these derived types that require certain values to be passed to `foo`.

Comment: If we don't  touch the class hierarchy,   using 'typeid' in Event::execute maybe a solution.

Comment: @ grizzlybears  Will this solution scale well?  So when new derived types of `Thing` also need this behaviour, then this typeid check in `Event` will need to be updated?

Comment: static Thing s_dummy;
    void execute(Thing& thing) {
        thing.foo( typeid( thing) == typeid( s_dummy) );
    }

Comment: If more classes derived from `Event`, we can still let the `Event::execute()` do the dirty work. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need `Thing` to behave differently depending on the caller, then you need to tell it who the caller is.  You also need to separate the implementation from the default parameters, probably with `virtual` methods.

```
struct Thing {
    enum {CALLER_NOT_EVENT, CALLER_IS_EVENT} Caller;

    virtual ~Thing () {}
    void foo(Caller callerIsEvent, bool b) {
        std::cout << "Thing::foo() called with b = " << std::boolalpha << b << ".\n";
    }
    virtual void foo(Caller callerIsEvent) 
    {foo(callerIsEvent, false); }
};

struct Blob : Thing {
    virtual void foo(Caller callerIsEvent) 
    {foo(callerIsEvent, callerIsEvent==CALLER_IS_EVENT); }
};

struct Event {
    void execute(Thing& thing) { thing.foo(CALLER_IS_EVENT); }
};
```

You can also play games with template or `typeid`, but in my opinion, an explicit enum is a lot cleaner and easier.

Comment: @ Mooing Duck   Value false is to be passed only for type `Blob` (and certain other derived types of `Thing`) though.  But I see the idea that I the code must not compile if `Thing::foo()` is called without passing something.  I think perhaps `thing.foo(*this)` should be called, then Thing::foo(Event&)` can be overridden by `Blob` while `Thing::foo(T&)` for any other type `T` will use the default behaviour.

Comment: @prestokeys Exactly. I've now added `virtual` methods so that Event calling `Blob::foo` without an explicit parameter will pass `true` instead of `false.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mooing Duck's ideas, I've come up with something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Event;

struct Thing {
    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_base_of_v<Event, T>>>
    void foo (T& t, bool b = true) { fooBasic(b); }
    virtual void foo(Event&, bool b = true) { fooBasic(b); }
private:
    virtual void fooBasic(bool b = true) {  // Cannot be called from Event.
        std::cout << "Thing::fooBasic() called with b = " << std::boolalpha << b << ".\n";
    }
};

struct Blob : Thing {
    void foo(Event&, bool = true) override { fooBasic(false); }
    void fooBasic(bool b = true) override {
        std::cout << "Blob::fooBasic() called with b = " << std::boolalpha << b << ".\n";
    }
};

struct Event {
    void execute(Thing& thing) { thing.foo(*this); }  // 'thing.foo();' will not compile.
};

int main() {
    Blob blob;
    Event event;
    event.execute(blob);
}
```